# Do the religious figures leading a particular See of Christianity have a specific title(s) for that office?

Tags: church-hierarchy

For instance:

*Pope Francis, Bishop of Rome, _____ of the (Western) See*

*Emperor Claudius XI, last _____ of the (Eastern?) See*

I've also seen the term "synod"; I'm not sure where that fits in either.

I'm not looking for other political distinctions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leader of the Coptic Orthodox Church of Alexandria carries the title of **Pope**. The present incumbent is [Pope Tawadros II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Tawadros_II_of_Alexandria).

> Pope Tawadros II (English: Pope Theodore II]) born 4 November 1952, is the 118th and current Pope of Alexandria and Patriarch of the See of St. Mark, succeeding the late Pope Shenouda III as leader of the Coptic Orthodox Church of Alexandria. He took office on 18 November 2012, two weeks after being selected.

Only two other religious leaders carry the title of pope. One being that of Pope Francis (for Catholics) and the other being the other being the Greek Orthodox Patriarch of Alexandria who has the title of [Pope and Patriarch of Alexandria and All Africa.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_Orthodox_Patriarchs_of_Alexandria).

In addition to the title of **pope**, the leader of the Catholic Church carries the following official papal titles:

> [Papal Titles](https://www.ewtn.com/jp2/papal3/titles.htm):
>
> - His Holiness The Pope;
> - Bishop Of Rome And Vicar Of Jesus Christ;
> - Successor Of St. Peter, Prince Of The Apostles;
> - Supreme Pontiff Of The Universal Church;
> - Patriarch Of The West;
> - Servant Of The Servants Of God;
> - Primate Of Italy;
> - Archbishop And Metropolitan Of The Roman Province;
> - Sovereign Of Vatican City State.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope) states:

> The title 'Pope' is an informal one; the formal title of the Pope is 'Bishop of Rome, Vicar of Jesus Christ, Successor of the Prince of the Apostles, Supreme Pontiff of the Universal Church, Patriarch of the West, Primate of Italy, Archbishop and Metropolitan of the Roman Province, Sovereign of the State of the Vatican City, Servant of the Servants of God', although this is rarely seen or used in full...

Comment: It seems *Patriach* is a consistent answer for the two Sees mentioned. Greek and Eastern Orthodox anyone?

Comment: This is not quite correct - the Greek Orthodox patriarch of Alexandria is known as ["The Pope and Patriarch of Alexandria and All Africa"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_Orthodox_Patriarchs_of_Alexandria).

Answer (score 2):

Typically, in Catholicism, in Eastern or Oriental Orthodoxy, and in the Assyrian Church of the East, the highest-ranking bishops of a particular see are given the title [Patriarch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patriarch). The see itself can also be called a *patriarchate*.

Note however that this title of *patriarch* applies, within the Catholic Church, not only to the pope as head of the whole Catholic Church but also to the heads of the various Catholic Churches *sui iuris*, such as the Melkite and Maronite Catholic Churches. I'm not aware of any title that applies to (for example) *only* the pope within the Catholic Church and also to the heads of all other Orthodox and Eastern churches.